# Why is it necessary to follow Nitya Karma and Niyama(rules)?

Tags: karma, yama

It is personal to follow dharma. But still there are necessary to follow some rules like nitya krama and niyama.

Why is it necessary to follow Nitya Karma and Niyama(rules)? Also practically how many of them can be followed individually for a samsari?

Comment: Karma and Niyama differes for people belonging to varna and ashrams.However the goal of human life is one; that is to attain freedom from cycle of birth and death and in this en-devour 1st step is to understand God. In this connection there is verse in mahabharat which says eating,sleeping,mating and defending is common to animals and humans; but Dharma is the only thing that is specific to human being and without dharma; Human is as good as animal. Hence in order to come to an understanding of God it is very important to follow Dharma.That is my opinion

Comment: Good question. It depends on your goal. If you want to lose weight, you have to follow strict diet and exercise isn't it! Similarly, different religious practices are prescribed for different goals. Similarly there are different goals for spiritual aspirants. Some want material benefits, some want magical powers, only few want God, for the sake of God. If you want Bhakti, then you have to take steps to Love God. If you want Jnana, then you have to take steps to Know Thyself. Similarly Karma Yoga or Vairagya.Thus depending on what you want, you need to be sincere, steadfast and you will get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We all are pleasure seeking entities. We want happiness. Without following rules(Niyama) and Regulations(Nitya Karma) there cannot be any real happiness in life. This is confirmed in Bhagvad-Geeta(3.10).

> In the beginning of creation, the Lord of all creatures sent forth
>   generations of men and demigods, along with sacriﬁces for Viṣṇu, and
>   blessed them by saying, “Be thou happy by this yajña [sacriﬁce]
>   because its performance will bestow upon you everything desirable for
>   living happily and achieving liberation.”

These rules and regulations are already described in different sections of Vedas. The importance of following dharma is stressed again in following verses:

> All living bodies subsist on food grains, which are produced from
>   rains. Rains are produced by performance of yajña [sacriﬁce], and
>   yajña is born of prescribed duties.
>
> My dear Arjuna, one who does not follow in human life the cycle of
>   sacriﬁce thus established by the Vedas certainly leads a life full of
>   sin. Living only for the satisfaction of the senses, such a person
>   lives in vain.

This second verse quoted above mentions the fate of those who don't follow these rules and regulations.
In general people are reluctant to follow these rules and regulations simply because they find them to be hindrance to their freedom. But Acharyas such as [Srila Prabhupada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._C._Bhaktivedanta_Swami_Prabhupada) calls these rules as "**rules and regulations of freedom**".

To experience the higher degree of freedom we have to voluntarily give up some freedom; i.e. follow these codes of conduct mentioned in scriptures even though we might have aversions for them.

An Example may be taken of driving on road. Eventhough we are free to drive a car on road;we have to follow the rules of traffic; otherwise the freedom to drive(in case of accident or some legal action) will be totally taken away from a person.

So those people who do not follow the cycle of sacrifice is put into helish condition of life; such as life of an animal,insect,tree etc. wherein the freedom is totally taken away and the living entity becomes a puppet in the hands of material nature.

hence in 2nd chapter of Geeta(2.40) while speaking about working without fruitive desire Krishna Says:

> In this endeavor there is no loss or diminution, and a little
>   advancement on this path can protect one from the most dangerous type
>   of fear.

Here "most dangerous type of fear" refers to a fear of being cast into hellish form of existence as I've mentined above.

**regarding your 2nd Question:**
**Also practically how many of them can be followed individually for a samsari?**

Vedas in them self are huge and describe number of rules and regulations to be followed by person desiring to achieve a particular goal(including Liberation from material world). In addition there are books such as Manu-smriti which outline the codes of conduct for human society.

**It will totally vary from person to person as to how many of these rules he can follow.**

Comment: BG 3.10 talks about Brahma and not Vishnu. See the [correct translation](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-03-10.html).

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Im refering to Vedabase.com. Translation may be different from other acharyas. But the point I was trying to make is that by performing Yagnya(sacrifice); we become happy. Vishnu is also called yagnya-Purusha. Since he is the enjoyer of all sacrifices. see BG5.29.BTW even in the translation that you have linked. It is mentioned 'sacrifice unto supreme lord'.

Comment: Well, the sanskrit verse says "prajapati" and prajapati is brahma, also supreme lord doesn't implies Vishnu.

Comment: ya 'prajapati' is translated as 'Lord of creatures';It is not translated to Vishnu anywhere in verse.'prajapati' indeed means Brahma. just that instead of Brahma 'lord of creatures' word is used. that is the same thing. For vaishnavas 'Supreme Lord' is Vishnu :)